# I can not install "See Install Kinect Driver in our previous post." in http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/8/

Tags: turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this web tell how to install driver of kinect,but I can ont finish it sucessfully,who can tell me why,I am really thanks for everyone

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205505/i-can-not-install--%22see-install-kinect-driver-in-our-previous-post.%22-in-http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/01/8//) by [jiao wei](https://answers.ros.org/users/21931/jiao-wei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hope this be helpful!
http://answers.ros.org/question/196455/kinect-installation-and-setup-on-ros-updated/

---

Originally posted by [sony](https://answers.ros.org/users/22164/sony/) with karma: 16 on 2015-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0